# JS declaration or statement expected - under script tags in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){


    string savePath = "c:\\uploads\\";


    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {

        int fileSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;


        if (fileSize < 2100000)
        {


            savePath += Server.HtmlEncode(FileUpload1.FileName);

            FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);


            UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Your file was uploaded successfully.";
        }
        else
        {

            UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Your file was not uploaded because " +
                                 "it exceeds the 2 MB size limit.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UploadStatusLabel.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload.";
    }
}
</script>
```

With this script that I'm adding into my CSHTML file within my ASP.NET application I'm getting an error stating "(JS) Declaration or statement expected" on the first line where I am declaring the protected void function. No idea what this means so how to resolve it.

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5wcK.png)

Comment: Show us the full error log please.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I've added the error log to the question